# Where do I store web server login credentials?

Tags: azure, web-server, node.js, azure-web-apps

I am building a web server that will accept requests from mobile devices and route to 2 different SQL Server instances. For extra security, I want the mobile devices to have to log in twice - log in to the web server and then log in to SQL Server.

If I'm using ExpressJS (with Typescript), where/how would I store the web server logins? Would I use some npm package or something?

This web server might be hosted on Azure - would Azure have a way for me to create a database to store web server logins?

Comment: **I want the mobile devices to have to log in twice - log in to the web server and then log in to SQL Server** - That sounds like a good way to alienate and lose users/customers. The burden of securing your website should fall on you, not be passed on to your users as extra hoops to jump through.

Comment: @joeqwerty this project isn't customer-facing

Comment: You still have customers, even if they are only internal, and this will annoy them

Comment: @SamCogan there are specific reasons why this must happen but they aren't relevant to the question. Please assume I'm ok with annoying my users